# Why can I not filter_by a field in my model when using a datetime as the data type?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm sure the title isn't super clear so here is some more explanation, I have a model set up like this:

```
class Event(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    event_tag = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    event_title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    event_short = db.Column(db.String(500))
    event_long = db.Column(db.Text)
    event_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Event %r>' % (self.event_tag)
```

I can create records in the database just fine using:

```
event1_futureDate = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=5)
event1 = models.Event(timestamp=datetime.utcnow(), event_title='event1', event_tag='friendly_url_tag', user_id=event_user.id, event_date=event1_futureDate, event_short='short event descr.', event_long='Long event description!')
db.session.add(event1)
db.session.commit()
```

and pull the information like this:

```
>>> event1 = models.Event.query.get(1)
>>> event1.event_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 27, 4, 42, 44, 372682)
```

or like this:

```
>>> event2 = models.Event.query.filter_by(event_tag='friendly_url_tag').first()
>>> event2.event_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 27, 4, 42, 44, 372682)
```

but trying to query with filter_by with a db.DateTime field results in an error like this:

```
>>> events = models.Event.query.filter_by(event_date>datetime.utcnow()).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'event_date' is not defined
```

I am unsure as to why I can not use the event_date filed in the model in the filter_by part of the query.

I know the field exists, the code below works as a by-pass for the time being. I don't like it and would rather do this in the original select and not get the entire table.

```
@web.route('/calendar')
def calendar():
    events = Event.query.all()
    showEvents = []
    for event in events:
        if event.event_date >= datetime.utcnow():
            showEvents.insert(0,event)

  return render_template('partial-calendar.html', events=showEvents)
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter_by` takes keyword arguments, not expressions. You can't use `>` in it, only `=`.

You want to use `filter` instead, like: `filter(models.Event.event_date > datetime.utcnow())`

Comment: This is what has been the cause of all my troubles... Thanks!